# How to train completely new entities instead of pre-trained entities using Spacy NER model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

How do I do transfer learning i.e. take pre-trained Spacy NER model and make it learn new entities specific to my use case?

For this, I have 100 new annotated training samples. The new retrained model should only predict the new entities and not any of the existing entities in the pre-trained spacy model. Just adding/updating new entities to existing models and ignoring the old entities during prediction doesn't make sense.

This [official example](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/examples/training/train_new_entity_type.py) describes how to add new entities to existing pre-trained entities but that's not what I want. I also have very few examples i.e. 100 to completely built a new NER model from scratch.

Edit: I want to identify all account numbers in an unstructured document.

Example 
("I would like to change address corresponding to my account 12345. Kindly let me know how to do it. " [34, 39, 'accountnumber'])

Comment: Need more info to answer the question - what type of entities are you working with? Place names, people names, etc.? Can you give example of the new entities and the training data for them?

Comment: Thanks. Added to the post

Answer (score 2):

You mention that you only want to predict the new entities, and not the old ones. There is thus no reason to start from a pre-trained NER model. The features learnt for the other entity types (that you don't want) won't be used/transfered to your new entity type anyway. So you'll just have to start training a model from scratch.

You mention that you only have a few training examples (100), so (as you mention) it will be a challenge to achieve high enough accuracy. Perhaps you could consider running a [rule-based matching step](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#_title) first, and then manually consolidate the hits from that matching step to augment your training data more quickly.

Comment: +1.  Do you mean to say this i.e. collect new examples and apply "rule-based matching" step to tag the entities in the new examples instead of manually annotating? If so cant i just apply the model trained on 100 examples and apply it on the newly collected examples to generate more training examples instead of  using "rule-based matching"?

Comment: Why do you think existing pretrained model wont be usefull for identify account number i.e. by just retraining the output layer with only account number? Isnt that the whole idea behind transfer learning?

Comment: Oh, sure, if you have the resources to do more manual annotations, that would be better than rules+curation !

Comment: Ok. What's the pros and cons of using rule based matching compared to automatically annotating new samples using the model trained on existing 100 examples? I am trying to understand when I should use the matcher

Comment: I would personally recommend using the matcher if you feel like there is little lexical/syntactic variation in your dataset. If you could capture 80% of your "gold" cases with a handful of rules, it might be worthwhile using the matcher for a first quick "sweep", and then do a manual annotation.

Answer (score 1):

For your use case, you are adding a new entity type so there should not be confusion with existing entity types. If you call your new entity "accountnumber", you should be able to use the training script you linked to train a model.

For the extraction phase, use the [code in the documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#named-entities) but just filter for the "accountnumber" in the results (i.e. ent.label_ field) and ignore the other existing entities.

Comment: The model build the way explained will be weaker than a model trained only to identify account number. Also the probability of prediction won't make sense and I want to use the probability further.

Comment: What's your basis for saying that the model will be weaker? Your new entity type does not overlap with the existing entities. SpaCy is using dependency parsing and other linguistic analysis to find entities. As long as you are not overlapping examples, you should be OK. Have you tried this and found the performance lacking?

Comment: spacy is building a residual CNN to make ner prediction. Based on what you are saying the last layer i.e. target contains say 1000 entities but i only want to account_type in the last layer. Since model trained to predict only account_type would be more accurate than model trained for predict aacount_type and 999 other  classes.

Comment: The only way to tell is to actually try it but I see NER as a two step problem. The first part is to distinguish what's an entity of interest from the rest of the text (e.g. verbs, prepositions, etc.). The second step is to identify what kind of entity it is. The first step is where I see the value of a pre-trained model. If you had a larger dataset, training a model from scratch would work.